# A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'int'

Tags: flutter

What am i trying to do is to sort my list by price .I am getting this error.

How can i fix this.Thanks in advanced

```
    sortAll(List<BookModel> books) {
    books.sort((a, b) {
      a.price.compareTo(b.price);
    },);
    print((books));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compareTo` is not returning anything. Try this instead:

```dart
books.sort((a, b) {
  return a.price.compareTo(b.price); // note the RETURN
},);
```

Or this:

```dart
books.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price) ); // implicit RETURN
```